# Remove all the unnecessary characters from a string of English words and Chinese characters

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

Is there any preg_replace function (or any other method) to remove all the unnecessary characters from a string of English words and Chinese characters. Unnecessary characters include all the special characters (including underscores), and numbers. Please note that I do not want spaces to get removed, nor the connected hyphens.

For example:

Input : "我来到北京清华大学 ! hey i am matt - @ * + = 123 45 6 7 890 .._my-you"

Output : "我来到北京清华大学 hey i am matt my-you"

Comment: It will be hard to predict what is unnecessary if content is user provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[!@*+=._]|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)|\d
```

also put anything else that you want to remove in this block `[!@*+=._]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9idExf/1)

Sample Source:

```
$re = '/[!@*+=._]|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)|\d/u';
$str = '我来到北京清华大学 ! hey i am matt - @ * + = 123 45 6 7 890 .._my-you';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Rizwan! Really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: If that helps you then I would appreicate if you accept that as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have upvoted as well but since my reputation is not that much, the upvote doesn't show up. Well, thanks again.

Comment: What if I also want to remove all the emojis from the string?